# Exception: Invalid database driver. Check your .env file and make sure the DB_CONNECTION variable

Tags: azure-web-app-service, blazor-server-side

I get an error after deploying a Blazor app to a web app. Everything works locally ok.

Here is the full error:

Exception: Invalid database driver. Check your .env file and make sure the DB_CONNECTION variable is set to mysql, sqlite, postgres, or sqlserver.
Spark.Library.Database.DatabaseServiceRegistration.AddDatabase(IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration config)

ENV settings:
APP_NAME=TestProject
ENVIRONMENT=dev

DB_CONNECTION=sqlserver
DB_HOST=testproject.database.windows.net
DB_PORT=1433
DB_DATABASE=****
DB_USERNAME=****
DB_PASSWORD=****
DB_TRUST_CERTIFICATE=true
DB_INTEGRATED_SECURITY=false

My web app settings:

- .net7
- 64 bit
- Integrated pipeline
- Always on = true

App service Plan: B1

I'm using the Spark.NET framework for my application.

Comment: Issue is resolved. Needed to add environment variables in Azure.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because User has resolved the issue themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is resolved. Needed to add environment variables in Azure.